# Begun.ru API + Python

Tags: python, soap

Привет всем.

Cтолкнулся с задачей: разобраться с api бегун.ру средствами python.
Протокол SOAP, на котором у них основано взаимодействие, откровенно говоря, вижу впервые, из документации от самого бегуна, кроме названия методов и принимаемых параметров, также ничего не ясно..  Поиски по гуглу дали только один вразумительный example и тот за 2010-й год и то на php. Достучатся до разрабов и получить хоть какие-то ответы пока не удалось... все необходимые логины пароли на руках имею.

Итак вопрос: кто работал с api бегуна на python, какую из множества soap-lib использовали вы? И если можно, пример авторизации и тестового запроса именно на бегун.

P.S:  Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOAP - протокол же. Следовательно, без разницы, какую либу использовать, главное чтобы поддержка стандарта была хорошо и правильно реализована.
Я использовал SUDS (не для бегуна, а вообще). В общем, выбирайте